# Full example of using template comparator

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am trying to a template class driven with a template parameter of `std::less`, `std::greater` or. This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702435/parameter-to-use-stdgreater-or-stdless-as-argument) since, the answer doesn't provide a full example and I am unable to successfully use the template comparator.

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename C>
class Test
{
    int compare(int l, int n, int x, int y)
    {
        public:
        bool z = C(x, y);
        if(l < n && z)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<std::less<int>> foo;
    Test<std::greater<int>> bar;
    foo.compare(1, 2, 3, 4);
    bar.compare(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Comment: Change `bool z = C(x, y);` to `bool z = C{}(x, y);`.

Comment: What does "I can't get it to work" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `C` (i.e. `std::less<int>` or `std::greater<int>`) is the type name, not the instance. `bool z = C(x, y);` won't work when `C==std::less<int>`, because `C(x, y)` will be interpreted as the construction of `std::less<int>`, which will fail because `std::less` doesn't have such constructor, and `std::less` can't be converted to `bool`.

You might mean call `operator()` on the instance of `C`, you could change it to

```
bool z = C()(x, y);
```