# std::min/std::max as template comparators

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Motivated by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558746/full-example-of-using-template-comparator) using `std::less/std::greater`.
Is it possible to use `std::min` or `std::max` as a template comparator?

The following example throws the error:

`error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class C> class Test'`

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename C>
class Test
{
public:
    int compare(int x, int y)
    {
        return C()(x, y);
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<std::min<int>> foo;
    Test<std::max<int>> bar;
    foo.compare(1, 2);
    bar.compare(1, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) are function templates. If you want to use them as template parameters, you need to declare them as [non-type template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter), such as function pointer:

```
template <const int& (*C)(const int&, const int&)>
class Test
{
public:
    int compare(int x, int y)
    {
        return C(x, y);
        //      ~~ Note no () here
    }
};
```

Comment: So with two template parameters, `template <typename T, const T& (*C)(const T&, const T&)>  ?`

Comment: @pyCthon Yes, you can. And use them as `Test<int, std::min<int>> foo;`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::min<int>` and `std::max<int>` are not types. They are functions.

```
Test<std::min<int>>
```

The `Test` template expects its parameter to be a class (or, rather, a type), not a function. The template is declared as:

```
template <typename C> class Test
```

`typename` means that the template parameter is a class/type.

Additionally, the template declares a method called "compare". `main()` attempts to invoke a method called "run". That would be another problem.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the function name, also why would `std::less` work and not `std::min`?

Comment: @pyCthon `std::less` is a `struct`, `std::min` is a function

Answer (score 1):

It std::min and std::max are functions not classes. Probably using Functor class template to wrap std::min/max functionality is also a better option as in code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename C>
class Test
{
public:
    int compare(int x, int y)
    {
        return C()(x, y);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class MinComp {
public:
    T operator ()(T x, T y) {
        return std::min<T>(x,y);
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<MinComp<int>> foo;
     std::cout<<foo.compare(5, 2);

}
```